# create animation in angular js after data changes

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have created a slider which slides 3 data at one time. But i want to add some animation like that of real slide. How do i do in angular js? I have code like below

moverightRecArts changes the startIndexArt and endIndexArt values from controller.

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="a in abc.slice(startIndexArt, endIndexArt)" >
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <img ng-src="{{a.url}}">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>{{a.sub}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>{{a.bod}}</p>                                    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-move-next-Art'>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" ng-click="moverightRecArts()"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's easy to accomplish, but setting a demo to test is tedious. So if you want good answer you should create a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

### Dynamic Animation

You have to call animation function like

```
<ion-view class="myAnimation">
    <ion-content>
        ....
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and add class when page is loaded

```
$('#myAnimation').addClass('animated shake');
```

and after animation finish you have to remove class which is added to div so again animation works without refresh page. for that you have to do that

```
$('#myAnimation').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', removeClass);

function removeClass()
{
    $('#myAnimation').removeClass('animated shake');
}
```

This way is dynamic but you can also set as static in html like

### Static

```
<ion-view class="animated shake">
    <ion-content>
        ....
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```